# Get an external IP for a Kubernetes LoadBalancer on Openstack

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

I'm just new with `Kubernetes`, I'm using `OpenStack` and I would like to create a load balancer to access my `NodeJs` server running on 3 pods. I get a pending loop when my load balancer try to get its public ip. I'm using `kubeadm` with `calico`.

[Screen: Pending External IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmaTV.png)

Comment: Have you configured the cloud provider for OpenStack? e.g. https://medium.com/@arthur.souzamiranda/kubernetes-with-openstack-cloud-provider-current-state-and-upcoming-changes-part-1-of-2-48b161ea449a

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround method. You can mention the external IP:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-js
  labels:
    name: node-js
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
  - 10.240.0.4
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30000
  selector:
    name: node-js
```